# Do I need a VPS for a custom built small TCP socket server, or is there a free service?

Tags: java, tcp, vps

I'm trying to build a multiplayer game in Java on a TCP based server. I have wrote the server, but I have no idea how I would deploy this to the net. Most of the services I've looked at are WSGI or are very limited, and wouldn't support my application. Do I need a VPS to host this, or is there a free service out there that does the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Web Services has a free usage](http://aws.amazon.com/free/?utm_source=AWS&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=LP_hero) for tier for one year that you can probably qualify for. You could set up a EC2 instance and run your application there.